# about static methods and variables

Tags: java, android, oop

why used this codes in [AEinsam/HabReader](https://github.com/AEinsam/HabReader/blob/master/src/net/meiolania/apps/habrahabr/auth/User.java):

```
private static User instance = null; // line:25

public static User getInstance() {
if (instance == null)
    instance = new User();
return instance;
}

// line:31
```

can I make class without this method?

Comment: Yes; it is possible to create a class with putting that code in it.

Comment: It's a bad singleton.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis +1 for pointing out that it's bad, for several reasons even - here's a [JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html) explaining some of the issues.

Comment: why -1 for question ;'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is (a ***poorly implemented***) [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  If you omit this static block but do not create a public constructor then your class might be useless.  If you are looking for an alternative that behaves the same way I (and most others on SO) would direct you to the [Enum Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/16959)

Comment: Emphasis on the _poorly implemented_

Comment: One reason why it is 'poorly implemented' is because it does not define a private default constructor 'private User() {}'. This means there can still be multiple instances of this User class.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern which means that class is supposed to have only one instance existing.

Answer (score 1):

The writer of that code wants to make sure there is only a single instance of the User class. This design pattern is called 'singleton'.

Yes, you can make a class without the method, but there could be multiple instances of that class.